# How can I change the Blade template file extention from *.blade.php to only *.blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I know Laravel's blade template resides in /resource/views directory. And it's extension is **.blade.php** .

My problem is I have set a separate repo for front end designer to work on blade template, and the repo is set restricted to push any file with an **.php** extension.

So what if I change all the **.blade.php** file to **.blade** file! By doing so laravel is unable to fine the view file.

How can I manage it.

Comment: You can use the `some_view.blade`, check my answer.

Comment: It's a bad idea and an anti-pattern.

Comment: @jeremykenedy Any logic for why it is a bad idea?

Comment: .php files are protected to not be able to be viewed as plain text, a .blade will be able to be read as plain text and will create a security risk. When you change the integrity of the template system it weakens it. A lot of opinions, considerations, and design was put into the templating system. Imagin having a car and saying you do not want to use the wheels but install Skis instead and expect it to run as it should..

Comment: @jeremykenedy I have found no security hole in changing the extension, because every blade template is residing in a directory above public root directory of the web server, So until I miss-configure the web-server there is no way to see the view as plain text at browser, and same thing applies for php extension. And this option is available into Laravel, please check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily add your custom `extension`, `Laravel` provides an easy way out of the box. Just open `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` file and add the following code in the `boot` method (Don't forget to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;` at the top of the class after `namespace App\Providers;`):

```
public function boot()
{
    View::addExtension('blade', 'blade');
}
```

Now, you can use something like this, for example:

```
Route::get('/example', function () {
    return view('example', ['name' => 'The Alpha']);
});
```

In this case, you should create a view in `views` directory using name `example.blade`, for example (`resources/views/example.blade`):

```
<!-- Also a master.blade should be in views/layouts directory -->
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    Hello {{ $name }}
@endSection
```

This is the `resources/views/layouts/master.blade` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel Custom Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If everything goes right then you should see `Hello The Alpha` when visiting the `/example` route. So, the only thing is to add a new `extension` using the `View::addExtension('extension', 'engine)`, in this example, I've used `blade` as engine so you can use all the `blade` directives/syntax. Alternatively, you can use `php` as engine, these are available by default (also `file`) and if you use `php` as engine then you can't use `blade` directives/syntax.

Comment: It's working perfectly, with just two line added.

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View; 

and

View::addExtension('blade', 'blade');

into the AppServiceProvider

Thanks a lot, this option is missing into Laravel Documentation or may be I missed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom view factory class by extending the `Illuminate\View\Factory` class. Within that class, modify the `$extensions` property:

```
protected $extensions = [
        'blade' => 'blade', // add this entry
        'blade.php' => 'blade',
        'php' => 'php',
        'css' => 'file',
        'html' => 'file',
    ];
```

Then, create a new service-provider, and use it to bind your custom factory to the `View\Factory` interface:

```
$this->app->bind(
            'Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory',
            'App\YourCustomerViewProvider'
        );
```

And that should be it. Note: I have not tested this, so it may need to be tweaked.